# how to create curved connectors in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013

I have been trying to replicate the curved lines in the image below.

I'm not even halfway close to the model below. Can someone help me understand if we can replicate sthg like this in WORD or any other MS Office application.

[image: curved lines]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### I have been trying to replicate the curved lines

> **Draw a curve**
>
> 1. On the Insert tab, click Shapes.
> 2. Under Lines, click Curve.
> 3. Click where you want the curve to start, drag to draw, and then click wherever you want to add a curve.
> 4. To end a shape, do one of the following:
>
>    - To leave the shape open, double-click at any time.
>    - To close the shape, click near its starting point.

Source [Draw a curve or circle shape](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Draw-a-curve-or-circle-shape-bf9826a8-c21f-4a84-8823-cd90a079f0fd)

Comment: ah.. i had looked at this; but i paid close  attention to bullet point 3. also you can use the add/edit points feature to refine the curved line. thank you David.